# Spring Boot Application - Running the jar file locally gives JNI error (NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/servlet)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Migrated a legacy spring project to spring boot. Used the beans from the legacy xml file by importing the xml file as resource with @ImportResource annotation. Legacy spring project had web.xml file with servlet mapping and this is handled by creating a servlet bean in the application main class. Now the application is running fine locally and it is creating a jar file in the target folder. But when I try to run the jar file with command (java -jar myapp.jar), it gives an error as shown below.

```
Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
at java.lang.class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method).
```

The main class and the config file looks like below.

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherApiServlet() { 
  ServletRegistrationBean servRegBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(); 
  servRegBean.setServlet(new ServletContainer()); 
  servRegBean.addUrlMappings("/api/*"); 
  servRegBean.addInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application",
  "com.api.AppResourceConfig "); 
  servRegBean.addInitParameter("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl",
  "true"); 
  servRegBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  return servRegBean;
     }
    }
```

AppResourceConfig.java:

```
public class AppResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppResourceConfig {}{
      super();
    property("jersery.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server");
    packages("com.api");
    register(GsonProvider.class);
    register(RequestContextFilter.class);
    register(NotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
    register(DefaultExceptionMapper.class);
    }
    
}
```

I have multiple versions of Java in my system: java 8 and java 18. I have set the environment variable to point to java 8 and when check the java versions by using command java -version and javac -version and both are showing the same version (1.8). So this should not be an issue with multiple versions of java. For your information, I am using macbook to run my application

Comment: What does your `pom.xml` look like? Do you have `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency? Are you building with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`? Also Jersey support is backed into Spring Boot, which means you don't really need to add a servlet but just configure some parts in Spring Boot (`application.properties` and include dependencies) and provide your `ResourceConfig`.

Comment: The resource config is added and My pom file has spring-boot-starter-web dependency and I am building with spring-boot-maven-plugin.  Also I have added maven-jar-plugin with manifest as main class. <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> <version>3.3.0</version> <configuration> <archive><manifest> <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> <mainClass>com.api.application.Application</mainClass> </manifest></archive></configuration> </plugin>

Comment: My application works fine when I run from eclipse locally. But not working while running the jar file from the command prompt.

Comment: Don't add the jar plugin add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to generate a proper fat jar. That being said pleas don't add additional information as comments instead edit your question.

Comment: I removed the jar plugin from pom.xml file. Now it gives me error "no manifest attribute, in myaccount.jar". It is a multimodule spring boot project and I am creating a jar from the module which has the main class. The parent pom file has all the modules added and packaging as pom.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved after updating spring-boot-maven-plugin dependency with execution goal repackage as shown below. Also removed maven-jar-plugin dependency as
M. Deinum suggested.

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Thank you everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using maven ? If you are building a standlone jar., make sure to use `maven assembly` command instead of `clean install`

If bundles all the dependencies.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Yes this is a maven project and I run the command mvn clean install to build it. It is creating a jar file successfully inside target folder. Also when I run the application locally, the application is up and I am able to hit the rest end points successfully.

Comment: When using Spring Boot and using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin you can just run `mvn install` or `mvn package` and it will create the proper jar. You don't need to run `assembly`.

Comment: I tried with mvn clean install and mvn package, both cases I am getting the same error.

Comment: I tried with mvn clean install and mvn package, both cases I am getting the same error. For your reference, I have added maven jar plugin with manifest tag that contains the main class in the next comment.

Comment: <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>                                                            
          <configuration> <archive><manifest>       
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
              <mainClass>com.api.application.Application</mainClass>             
           </manifest></archive></configuration>
        </plugin>

Comment: @M.Deinum  'mvn package' just create a simple jar cannot run alone. 'mvn install' packages and installs in your local repo. 'mvn assembly' create a distributable standalone jar can be run using java -jar <jar-name>

Comment: I strongly suggest you go and read the Spring Boot documentation. You only need mvn package not install (the latter will only pollute your local maven repository). And `mvn assembly` isn't needed at all.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read my comment fully. I never suggested 'mvn install'.  And 'assembly' is widely used and nothing wrong in going for that.